# lost partition table after dist-upgrade (debian)

Tags: boot, apt, raid, boot-loader, debian-installer

My setup is as follows:
/dev/sda
-> /dev/sda/1  =  SSD, unecrypted, ext4 filesysstem, all files in single partitions OS install.

/dev/sdb
-> /dev/sdb1 - HDD, unencrypted, ext4 - linux raid (RAID1) member

and

/dev/sdc
-> /dev/sdc1 - HDD, unecrypted, ext4 - linux raid (RAID1) member

members of linux_raid RAID1 mounted as ext4 FS in /raid.

After upgrading from debian stretch to debian buster, using apt full-upgrade, it does not boot with error: No boot device found.

So I tried to access this box with a Debian Live flash disk in order to mount /dev/sda1 and make a grub-install --root-directory /dev/sda1 - this used to do the trick. The problem is, it says superblock is missing on /dev/sda and there is no sda1 (there is no partition table of any kind). Gparted is also able to see my sdb1 and sdc1 as linux raid members, but for sda it only sees it capacity in GB with no partition information whatsoever. How could this be? Are there any chances to fix this setup or should I just go ahead with a fresh install and lose the data?

Comment: of course, the ideal way to recover is to restore from a backup - I'm assuming you have no backup. So, try creating a partition on `/dev/sda` - perhaps the default "start" for the partition will be where it started before it was lost - fdisk may "spot" the ext4 signature and ask if you want to remove it ... the secret is, say no at this stage, and you may just restore your drive. Are you sure sda had one and only one partition though?

Comment: yes I am sure there was only one partition on sda of ext4 and maybe one for swap. I do not recall exactly I have no backups. I hope to recover the data. How can a simple dist-upgrade do this to the partition table?

Comment: it shouldn't (and hasn't in any of my 6+ upgrades)